# delegate and events

Tags: c#

Can someone give a practical example of delegate and events where delegate and events are the only solution of the problem ?

Comment: Hello, Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is this a homework question?

Comment: You are making this question too easy, only one common counter-example is required.  There is no way to get a button's Click notification without a delegate.

Answer (score 6):

Delegates and Events are *never* the *only* solution.

You can implement [observable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), use [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) directly and more to emulate the functionality.